# Help with creating a formula to calculate grade needed on test to pass?

Tags: average

This is probably a simple math question and yet I'm struggling to understand it, any help would be extremely appreciated.

Say if I have 2 test results,

50% on Test 1, test worth is 10% of final grade

50% on Test 2, test worth is 30% of final grade

and then I want to know:

____% on Test 3, test worth is 60% of final grade, if I want to get 50% in the course

^ I am about to take a third and final test. I am trying to write a formula where you can calculate the percent needed to pass.

I have tried:

(0.6 * Desired score of 0.50 + (1 - 0.6) * current grade), but I'm unsure how to calculate my current grade using the first two test results for use in a formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50% on Test 1 amounts to 0.5 x 10% of the overall grade = 5%.

50% on Test 2 ...... 0.5 x 30% = 15%.

Thus, from test 1 and 2 you have a total of 20%

if you want 50% overall, then you need to get a contribution of 50-20=30% from the final assessment.

30% from something that is worth 60% is just 30/60 = 50%.